# Creating a pointer to an array of strings in C

Tags: arrays, c

I would like to know if the method of creating a pointer to an array of strings  is the same with a one-dimensional. Most examples i found don't really answer my question so here it is:

Suppose we create the array:

```
    char a[6] = "Hello";
```

i define a pointer this way:

```
    char *ptr = a;      // also *ptr = &a[0];
```

from that i now can print the entire string or the single characters, e.g. :

```
     printf("%s", ptr );
     printf("%c", ptr[2] );
```

Now, is the same possible with a two-dimensional array of char? E.g. :

```
    char a[4][9] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
```

I could write:

```
    char *suits = &a[0][0];
```

and actually applying what i wrote above for the single string and characters, but i wonder if it is possible to do something like:

```
     char *suits = a;
```

and so print any string or characters of the array.

Comment: Well, why don't you try it and see what happens :)
Although in fact, the type is slightly off: it should be char **suits = a since two dimensional array is a pointer to pointers (arrays are pointers).

Comment: It should be `char *suits = a[0];` or  `char *suits = a[1];` etc. to then use the similar print statements.

Comment: @MMZK1526 yours generates a compiler warning, and "arrays are pointers" is incorrect.

Comment: @MMZK1526 No, `char**` is wrong in given case as `a` is not an array of pointers, but an array of arrays. If we want a pointer to iterate over the outer array it would need to have type of `char(*)[9]`, i.e. pointer to array of length 9!

Comment: The correct pointer declaration is `char (*suits)[9] = a;` which says that `suits` is a pointer to an array of characters of length 9.

Comment: @Weather Vane yes, that is correct, but this way i would need to create 4 pointers! How could i create only one ? This is my question.

Comment: By defining a type that describes the array. Otherwise the compiler can't know the inner dimension, which is essential to index a 2D array from pointer, which conveys no information apart from the type and an address.

Comment: @Weather Vane thank you for answering; if i may, could you provide an example?

Comment: Easier, would be this `char *a[4] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};` an array of string pointers. Now you can `printf("%s", a[1]);` or `printf("%c", a[1][0]);` for `Diamonds` and `D` respectively.

Comment: @Aconcagua Op [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73292290/creating-a-pointer-to-an-array-of-strings-in-c?noredirect=1#comment129437987_73292290) "How could i create only one (pointer)? This is my question." The revision makes it easy with the double-pointer.

Comment: @Aconcagua the point is, you can't define `char **` from a 2D array. Yes, you can print those values directly from a 2D array, but OP isn't asking that.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, but that was my point as well – *Now you can `printf(...)`* was your comment, but the pointer was not mentioned, just wanted to enlighten that pointer advantage ;) – *though* the pointers should now point to `const`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, your comment now is as is... I think we're just spoiling the question, I'll add a comment for the QA and we might drop our other comments, OK?

Comment: @Talete Note, though, that the string literals represent *immutable* string arrays, so you actually should refer to them as const: `char const* a[4] = { /*...*/ };`! This way undefined behaviour due to modifying string literals gets much less likely. The true benefit of is not the `printf`s, as mentioned (these are possible identically without it), but that you can define a pointer to the entire array much more easily: `char const** suits = a;` – without the change, it would have been possible, too, but more complicated: `char (*suits)[9] = a;` – as has been presented already.

Comment: @Aconcagua shouldn't  be ```const char *a[4] = .....``` or is it the same as ```char const* a[4] = ....``` ?

Comment: @Talete That's exactly the same. `const` always refers to the element *left* to it – *unless* there isn't any. Always placing `const` to the right is more consistent and prevents some confusion in some cases. You might encounter *west-consters* and *east-consters* some day – that refers exactly to where people place the `const`, me is part of the `east-conster` fraction ;)

Answer (score 0):

To index it you need pointer to array:

```
void printString(size_t cols, char (*strings)[cols], size_t pos)
{
    printf("Printing in function: String at index %zu: \"%s\"\n", pos, strings[pos]);
}

int main(void)
{
    char a[][9] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
    char (*ptrToArray)[9] = a;

    for(size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); index++)
    {
        printf("String at index %zu: \"%s\"\n", index, ptrToArray[index]);
        printString(sizeof(a[0]), a, index);
    }
}
```